# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Blue color' to data type int in stored Procedure sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying create a stored Proc . but it is throwing me "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Blue color' to data type int " error.I dont know where is wrong please help me

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerDiem] 

    @KeyWord varchar(10)


AS
BEGIN
set nocount on



 IF @KeyWord=1
 BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Jan,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**'  from PerDiem
    END 
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=2
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Feb,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=3
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Mar,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=4
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Apr,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=5
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,May,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=6
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Jun,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=7
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,JUl,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=8
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Aug,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=9
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Sep,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=10
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Oct,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    Else IF @KeyWord=11
    BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Nov,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    END
    ELSE IF @KeyWord=12    
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Dec,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem
    ELSE
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],County,Oct,Nov,Dec ,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**' from PerDiem 



    where [FiscalYEAR] =2015
    and [state] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
    or [City] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
    or [Zip] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
    or [County] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'


END
```

Comment: Is 'Blue color' the input you're giving to the procedure? You have @keyword defined as nvarchar but you're comparing it to numbers like it's the month number. Is there a need for another variable or should it be = '1'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as JamesZ said in comment you have declared parameter '@KeyWord' as `VARCHAR(10)` but compairing its value with integer in IF-Else like `IF @KeyWord=1` which is giving you error.

Altogether your logic is also not good for SQL query. I think you want different month based on your parameter so stored proc can be like :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerDiem] 

    @KeyWord INT


AS
BEGIN
set nocount on



 IF @KeyWord=1
 BEGIN
    Select City as 'Primary Destination',
         LocationDefined as [(County 2,3)],
         County,
         Month=CASE 
            WHEN @KeyWord=1 THEN 'Jan'
            WHEN @KeyWord=2 THEN 'Feb'
            WHEN @KeyWord=3 THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN @KeyWord=4 THEN 'Apr'
            WHEN @KeyWord=5 THEN 'May'
            WHEN @KeyWord=6 THEN 'Jun'
            WHEN @KeyWord=7 THEN 'Jul'
            WHEN @KeyWord=8 THEN 'Aug'
            WHEN @KeyWord=9 THEN 'Sep'
            WHEN @KeyWord=10 THEN 'Oct'
            WHEN @KeyWord=11 THEN 'Nov'
            WHEN @KeyWord=12 THEN 'Dec'
            ELSE 'Oct,Nov,Dec ,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep'
         END
         Meals as 'Meals & Inc. Exp.**'  
   from PerDiem        
    where [FiscalYEAR] =2015
     and [state] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
      or [City] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
      or [Zip] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'
      or [County] like '%'+@KeyWord+'%'


END
```

OR

Better Have a Varchar Parameter `@month Varchar(100)` & assign its corresponding value of month outside select loop using if else & use that single time computed variable in select.